# R CMD BATCH with crontab

Tags: r, cron, rscript

I execute R CMD BATCH using crontab(in centos7).

like this...

```
45 5 * * 5 R CMD BATCH /home/script/my_test.R
```

But i cant't find `my_test.Rout` file.

Where is `my_test.Rout` file?

Comment: Sorry, disregard my previous comment, it's `45 5 * * 5 Rscript /home/script/my_test.R`.

Comment: Or `45 5 * * 5 R CMD BATCH /home/script/my_test.R`.